# Cucumber HTML tag in feature

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I have a cucumber scenario where I wan to test for an HTML tag.

```
Scenario: enter words
    Given I enter "cat,dog"
    When I set tag to "li" and the class to "word"
    Then I should see "<li class=\"word\">cat</li>"
    And I should see "<li class=\"word\">dog</li>"
```

Is this the correct way to write this scenario?

Comment: Probably not, but it's hard to tell what your scenario is actually supposed to mean. Can you give some background?

Comment: It depends, are you testing an interface of an html editor? if so, it could be correct ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should aim to have your scenario's read in plain english. If I weren't a developer then the scenario wouldn't make much sense to me. You could do something like this:

```
Then I should see cat within a word list element
```

The step for this would be:

```
Then /^(?:|I )should see "([^"]*)" within (.*)$/ do |text, parent|
  with_scope(parent) do
    if page.respond_to? :should
      page.should have_content(text)
    else
      assert page.has_content?(text)
    end
  end
end
```

The cucumber generator should already provide the with_scope method but here it is anyways:

```
module WithinHelpers
  def with_scope(locator)
    locator ? within(*selector_for(locator)) { yield } : yield
  end
end
World(WithinHelpers)
```

And just be sure to add the selector to your selectors.rb in features/support/selectors inside the case statement for locator:

```
module HtmlSelectorsHelpers

  def selector_for(locator)
    case locator

    when ' a word list element'
      'li.word'
```